# Mysql join table order by index

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, query-performance

First Master Table

```
CREATE TABLE `edipostingmaster` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `applied` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unqiue` (`checkNo`,`fileName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

First Detail Table

```
CREATE TABLE `edipostingclaims` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `applied` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `claimSno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `claimNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `claimExists` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`fileName`,`checkNo`,`claimSno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=385 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Second detail table

```
CREATE TABLE `edipostingcodes` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `claimSno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `claimNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineItemNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `unique` (`checkNo`,`claimSno`,`fileName`,`lineItemNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1289 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the query

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM edipostingmaster a  , edipostingclaims b, edipostingclaims c
WHERE a.fileName = b.fileName AND a.checkNo = b.checkNo
AND b.fileName = c.fileName AND b.checkNo = c.checkNo AND b.claimSno = c.claimSno
AND a.checkNo ='893881996'
ORDER BY b.claimSno
```

Now explain showing `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort` for table a.
Without order by, it is fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're even asking... paste the query plan and sample data.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, while an index could be used (not in the current state, but if the index changed its column order a bit) to speed up the ordering, the optimizer has to decide between favoring the filtering or the ordering.

As it probably starts by filtering by the constant `a.checkNo ='893881996'`, and accessing first the table `a`, it would be impossible to get the records in `b.claimSno` order (even with different indexes).

As such, a sorting process is required at the end of the row retrieval, and that requires a temporary table. Do not be too worried unless the difference in time between each execution is very high.

If the table ends up being created on disk, you can try tuning `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` for that session to try to avoid that - although with the couple of `varchar(255)` that you have, it probably will be worse, not better. If the number of `sort_merge_passes` is very high, you can try tuning the `sort_buffer_size` for that session.

On the other hand, if the query is running fast enough for you, you do not need to worry as it is something normal.